# What's the google-play-services_lib jar's size?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm having the blank screen and zoom buttons issue and I think all permissions and my key codes are typed correctly, the project is registered at the Google's APIs Console site and Google Maps Android API v2 service is checked

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myProject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <permission android:name="com.myProject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/> 
 <uses-permission android:name="com.myProject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myProject.ScreenMap"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myKey"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So I was looking at that jar's path and it's size is only 1kb, so I'm curious if the jar is damaged since the google-play-services's jar's size is about 578kb

Comment: have you referred to google play services library properly? post your layout xml and your code

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the 1kb JAR phenomenon :

The Google Play Services Library Project itself doesn't contain any (real) java code. It contains a single dummy UnusedStub.java, simply because the Android tooling / build system needs at least 1 java class otherwise it is considered an invalid project.

```
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\src\android
```

This is in fact the 1kb JAR you are probably seeing.

The actual Google Play Services code is in the libs folder of the Google Play Services Library Project.

```
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services
```

That is 578kb JAR containing the `com.google.maps.gms` package and classes (the actual Google Maps V2 code.

If you didn't mess around with the library project, and simply added it as a reference to your project, you should see 2 JAR files in your projects `bin/dexedlibs` folder

- google-play-services_lib-85cb1c92715dbebbf9272cc8771ff1ee (1kb - the library project)
- google-play-services-802bdd645fa52832629ef9a428b8df7e (the JAR file in the libs folder of the library project)

I assume you have correctly imported the library project, otherwise your project would not be able to resolve any classes imported from the `com.google.maps.gms` package.

You need to check the ADB logs to see what is going on while the map is being displayed. Most likely it's an authentication issue. Double check your API key and the API console and make you sure you entered everything correctly :

[image]